# 301 redirect destination url format

Tags: .htaccess, seo

I am trying to do some 301 url redirect at my website, here are the first few lines of the .htaccess file :-

```
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]


Redirect 301 /en/home/index.html /index.php?
Redirect 301 /en/about/product.html /shop?
Redirect 301 /en/member/profile.html /index.php?route=account/account
```

All the above 3 301 rules works fine. But when I remove the "?" at first and second rule, the redirections fail. So in this case, "?" must be present.

However, if I wish to have the format that is without "?", is it possible?

Also, if I just do url rewrite, but not do 301 redirect, will it still maintain the previous seo achievements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using mod_rewrite instead of mod_alias:

```
RewriteRule ^en/home/index.html$ /index.php? [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^en/about/product.html$ /shop? [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^en/member/profile.html$ /index.php?route=account/account [L,R=301]
```

You're also going to want those before your index.php routing rule.